# Turbo C - Scanf to only accept one character

Tags: c, turbo-c

I want to make scanf only accept one character, but I am not familiar with the method of doing so. can anyone help me here.

here is my current code:

```
void push(S *stack){
      char e;
      S temp;
      temp=malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
      if(!temp){
         printf("Failed\n");
         return;
     }
     printf("Input value: \n");
     scanf(" %c", &e);
     if(('a'<=e && e<= 'z') || ('A'<=e && e<= 'Z')){
         temp->data=e;
         if(*stack == NULL){
            temp->next = temp->prev = NULL;
            *stack=temp;
         } else {
           temp->next = *stack;
           (*stack)->prev = temp;
           temp->prev = NULL;
           *stack=temp;
         }
    printf("Success %c", e);     
    }else{
        printf("Failed %c", e);
    }  
}
```

Forgot to mention:

if i were to input "abc" it will be pushed in the stack as a,b and c. though it is correct i was hoping to have a way to nullify the input and only accept it if its only a single character, if this is possible of course? if not then i will stick with the current one, was just hoping for a better implementation. thank you

Comment: your question isn't clear. maybe an example would help?

Comment: is space in format string  in scanf  problem ?

Comment: yes space is a problem, im sorry if im vague here. what i really want is for the user to push only 1 character in the stack per push

Comment: `(*stack)->prev = temp;` is most likely a bug. Does this actually compile? If so, get a _standard C compiler_ instead.

Comment: @Lundin how so? it works fine with me. though im using an old fashioned school required compiler.

Comment: Turbo C had plenty of inconsistencies with following the C90 standard. There were several issues, mainly of the kind where you wrote something not allowed in the C language, and then TC generated some crazy bananas code, instead of giving a compiler error. And of course TC doesn't follow the latest C standard either. If your school forces you to use TC, that's a certain indication of a poor quality class/teacher.

Comment: @Lundin can you give a name of a current best compiler for c? thank you, they have been using it for years now, i dont know why though they seem to trust it a lot.

Comment: @hushpuppies In my opinion, GCC. As for which IDE and debugger that is best for that compiler, it depends on what system you are using. I hope you aren't using MSDOS...

Comment: @Lundin will download that one, no i am using xp. :)

Comment: @haccks read your answer and posted a reply. thank you

Comment: Is the aim of the exercise to input one character or to use scanf?  If it is just to input one character, use getchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int ch;
...
printf("Input value: \n");
scanf(" %c", &e);

while( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);   // To eat up all the characters left behind by scanf call including '\n'.
```

`scanf` reads the first character you typed in to `e`. The rest of the characters left behind in the buffer is read one by one to `ch` by the `getchar` in `while` loop until it reads `\n`. When it reads `\n` then condition becomes `false` and the loop is terminate. Now your buffer is empty.

Comment: Shouldn't you check ch for EOF before executing getchar()? Seems odd to only check the return code from getchar and not from scanf. And well, in practice you can most likely just write `scanf(); getchar();` without all the fluff.

Comment: @Lundin; `scanf(); getchar();` would not help if the input is more than one character (excluding newline). Read the edit made by OP to the question.

Comment: @haccks tried it just now, and it ended up stuck at entering a character, had to do ctrl+pause/break to escape the loop. any ideas as to why that happened? thank you again

Comment: @hushpuppies; I forgot to mention that on TCC better to remove `EOF`. Just use `while( (ch = getchar()) != '\n')`.

Comment: @haccks what is EOF for exactly? its working great. thank you, if you could explain to me how it worked it would be better. thanks again :)

Comment: Well, if the input is more than one character, then the proper implementation is to use `fgets`. `scanf` shouldn't be used in production code.

Comment: @Lundin; Using `fgets` is not the solution. The only solution is to flush the buffer.

Comment: @haccks what is EOF for and how did this line of code helped my problem? thank you :)

Comment: @hushpuppies; I edited my answer how this solved your problem. Read more about `EOF` here: http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/eof.htm

Comment: @haccks: What you have there is an infinite loop - for it to stop `ch` must be `\n` and `EOF` at the same time. `&&` is the correct logic to continue if you have neither and stop if you have one of the two. Alternatively you could invert the whole statement, but I think that is less readable.

Answer (score 1):

Add one more line of code after `scanf`

```
 scanf(" %c",&e);
 getchar();
```

The `getchar` reads the new line, when you press enter after you type the character. Hope this helps.

Comment: No need to use `getchar`. There is already a space in the `scanf`'s specifier.

Comment: `getchar()` reads trailing new line character that is not read by `scanf`. Have you tried the code?

Comment: I think you can have a look at haccks answer.

Comment: If every scanf() call uses the `" %c"` syntax, then you don't need the extra getchar() to get the program to behave as expected. But of course there would still be a `\n` left behind then.

Answer (score 1):

And if you just dont want your program to wait for an **enter** after typing the character, use `getch()` defined in `<conio.h>`

```
c = getch();
```